# *Playtest feedback request* Puzzle 2

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle

This is the second puzzle in the series I'm working on. It's very different from the first as I tried to do different kinds of puzzles for each of these. In this one, players would have to find each of these images so to save that step I've just pasted them all below. The players then need to figure out the rest. The solution is a single English word.

Since this is my first attempt at making a puzzle series, feedback is encouraged.

---

[image: puzzle image 1 of 5]

[image: puzzle image 2 of 5]

[image: puzzle image 3 of 5]

[image: puzzle image 4 of 5]

[image: puzzle image 5 of 5]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The images refer to

> American university mascots.

From top to bottom, they are:

> **Southwestern** University
>  **Western** Washington University
>  Ohio **Northern** University
>  **Northeastern** University
>  **Northwestern** University

The numbers represent

> a Nonogram puzzle. Set them up according to the directions in the university names as so:
> NW N NE
> W
> SW
>  to get:
>  [image]

which, when solved, becomes:

> [image]

Thus, the answer must be

> **GO**

Comment: Nicely done! Out of curiosity, did you solve the nonogram by hand or did you use a solver? (I'm asking as this is a play test and I tried to make it harder for the online automated solver tools as there is technically some slightly different solutions that don't really change the image but the ambiguity does cause some of the online tools to just give an error and not show the answer.

Comment: I used a solver and iterated my way to the solution. The solver would only go so far, and then I'd have to break the ambiguities.

Comment: Gotcha. ok. I've done it by hand and it's doable but I did put in a little ambiguity as it breaks some solvers. Apparently there are others that will show you how far they got. :) Thanks for the notes!